# How to return the value after decoration?

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper

I used the following script for evaluating whether the values in function `test` are within the limits:

```
x=[-5,5]
def test(x):
    return x

def check(min,max):
     def decorator(func):
         def wrapper(*args,**kargs):
             y=func(*args,**kargs)
             for index in range(len(y)):
                 if y[index]>max:
                     y[index]=max
                 elif y[index]<min:
                     y[index]=min
             return func(*args,**kargs)
         return wrapper
     return decorator
```

In this test, the minimum is -1 and maximum is 1, so I used `check(-1,1)(test(x))` for decorating `test(x)`in order to get the expecting output value as `[-1,1]`. However, the output is:

```
<function __main__.check.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper>
```

which is not the expected `[-1,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wrapper should return `y`, the result of calling the undecorated function, rather than making a second call to it:

```
x=[-5,5]

def test(x):
    return x

def check(min, max):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
            y=func(*args, **kargs)
            for index in range(len(y)):
                if y[index] > max:
                    y[index] = max
                elif y[index] < min:
                    y[index] = min
            return y  # <- change to this
        return wrapper
    return decorator

test = check(-1, 1)(test)  # decorate test function

print(test(x))  # -> [-1, 1]
```

If you don't want to permanently decorate `test`, you could use this instead:

```
print(check(-1, 1)(test)(x))  # -> [-1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not wrapping the function correctly. The correct syntactic form is:

```
check(-1,1)(test)(x)

# check(-1,1)              -> returns func decorator 
#            (test)        -> returns func wrapper
#                  (x)     -> calls wrapper with one argument
```

Better to use the decorator syntax on the function directly tho:

```
@check(-1, -1)
def test(x):
    return x
```

And you should *return* `y`, the modified container, and not call `func` a second time in your `wrapper` function:

```
def wrapper(*args,**kargs):
      y = func(*args,**kargs)
      ...
      return y
```